# flake8 syntax error that I do not understand

Tags: python, python-3.x, flake8

I ran flake8 on my Employee program in order to check for PEP8 compliance and the only issue I have is a syntax error in the following line of code:

```
return print("Manager's ID:", self.id, "\nSalary:", self.salary,
```

can someone please tell me what the syntax error is in the line above?

For context, the line comes from a method called info() which displays some basic Employee object information:

```
def info(self):
    if isinstance(self, Manager):
      return print("Manager's ID:", self.id, "\nSalary:", self.salary,
                   "\nEmployee's under supervision:", self.print_supervisees(),
                   "\nManager started here on:", self.start_time)
    if isinstance(self, Supervisor):
      return print("Supervisor's ID:", self.id, "\nSalary:", self.salary,
                   "\nEmployee's under supervision:", self.print_supervisees(),
                   "\nSupervisor started here on:", self.start_time)
    elif isinstance(self, Developer):
      return print("Developer's ID:", self.id, "\nSalary:", self.salary,
                   "\nPrograming Language:", self.programming_language,
                   "\nDeveloper stated here on:", self.start_time)
    else:
      return print("Employee ID:", self.id, "\nSalary:", self.salary,
                   "\nEmployee stated here on:", self.start_time)
```

This syntax error is not thrown by my IDE and the info() method works fine for all Employees as far as I know.

Comment: you can't return a print, so either print or return the formatted string that you print

Comment: You may be running your linter in Python 2 mode. Also, `return print` is a really weird thing to do, and strongly suggests that you need to get a firmer understanding of how `return` and `print` work.

Comment: @hootnot: It's technically valid syntax in Python 3, but it's a bizarre thing to do.

Comment: it's valid in py3 because print is a (builtin) *function*

Comment: indeed valid in python3

Comment: Ah right, okay I see now; thanks guys!